# Android DataBinding, onItemrangeMoved - When does a block of entries move within a List?

Tags: java, android, list, collections, android-databinding

I'm currently playing around with Androids Data Binding library and it's [ObservableList](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableList.html).

But the method [onItemRangeMovedT(sender,int fromPosition, int toPosition, int itemCount)](https://ucwa.skype.com/appsdk/reference/Android/com/microsoft/office/sfb/appsdk/ObservableList.OnListChangedCallback.html#onItemRangeMoved-T-int-int-int-) is puzzling me.

Let's say the parameters are `sender = A, B, C, D, E`, `fromPosition = 0`, `toPosition = 2`, `itemCount = 2`

As I understand it, it would tell me following:

```
A                   C
B                   D
C   results in =>   A
D                   B
E                   E
```

But when does this happen? Is there a logic inside the ObservableList who watches the order of entries and calls automatically onItemRangeMoved if stimulated by a Collection.sort() or some convoluted Collections.rotate(l.sublist(j, k), x) stuff and even keep track of groups eg. [ab]cde -> cd[ab]e?

The `itemCount` parameter is really weirding me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableList.OnListChangedCallback.html):

```
void onItemRangeMoved (T sender, // The changing list.
            int fromPosition,    // The position from which the items were moved.
            int toPosition,      // The destination position of the items.
            int itemCount)       // The number of items moved.
```

> Called whenever items in the list have been moved.

---

Digging through `ObservableArrayList.class`, one will find a `ListChangeRegistry.class` which extends `ObservableList.OnListChangedCallback`. From the `ObservableArrayList.class` you can find methods like `set()`:

```
// mListener is an instance of ListChangeRegistry
@Override
public T set(int index, T object) {
    T val = super.set(index, object);
    if (mListeners != null) {
        mListeners.notifyChanged(this, index, 1);
    }
    return val;
}
```

This the called method:

```
/**
 * Notify registered callbacks that some elements have changed.
 *
 * @param list The list that changed.
 * @param start The index of the first changed element.
 * @param count The number of changed elements.
 */
public void notifyChanged(ObservableList list, int start, int count) {
    ListChanges listChanges = acquire(start, 0, count);
    notifyCallbacks(list, CHANGED, listChanges);
}
```

Which calls:

```
 @Override
 public void onNotifyCallback(ObservableList.OnListChangedCallback callback,
            ObservableList sender, int notificationType, ListChanges listChanges) {
        switch (notificationType) {
            case CHANGED:
                callback.onItemRangeChanged(sender, listChanges.start, listChanges.count);
                break;
            //more cases
        }
}
```

Since changes, moves, etc require to `set` the elements sometime, I guess that the `onItemRangeChanged` is triggered everytime - as the documentation states.